# Jacoco ant task - no jacoco.exec output

Tags: java, ant, jacoco

I configured my Ant task as

```
<target name="test" depends="init">
    <jacoco:coverage destfile="target/jacoco.exec">
        <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes" fork="yes" forkmode="once">
            <classpath refid="my_project.path"/>
            <formatter type="plain"/>
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <batchtest fork="false" todir="target/test-reports">
                <fileset dir="test">
                    <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </jacoco:coverage>
</target>
```

Which produces the expected junit result. However, the `target/jacoco.exec` is never created. I do not have any error during the `ant test report` task execution.

> test: [jacoco:coverage] Enhancing junit with coverage
>
> ```
> ...
>
> [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0,009 sec
> ```
>
> report: [jacoco:report] Loading execution data file
>   /home/usr/Workspaces/my_project/target/jacoco.exec
>
> BUILD FAILED /home/usr/Workspaces/my_project/build.xml:73: Unable to read
>   execution data file /home/usr/Workspaces/my_project/target/jacoco.exec
>
> Total time: 14 seconds

Seems like I am missing something, unable to see what exactly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the cause. It is stupid but there was no logging to indicate the error:

> > batchtest **fork="true"** todir="target/test-reports"

The fork parameter was set to false in the batchtest. Setting it back to "true" produces the expected **jacoco.exec**.

Comment: can you or someone elaborate which about which values are working for jacoco and why (having the same issue)

Answer (score 1):

Running the `report` task by itself is not sufficient. You will have to configure and run a `coverage` Ant task in order to enable coverage data to be recorder into the `jacoco.exec` file. See [here](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html#coverage)

Comment: I am calling `coverage` in the test task which is run before `report`.  Isn't that sufficient to create the output file?

Comment: Sorry, you are **running** the coverage task. Had the impression you are running the report task. Will obviously have to look again in your configuration. My apologies

Comment: @Olivier.Roger From the documentation:
_The nested task always has to declare fork="true", otherwise the coverage task can't record coverage information and will fail._
Is `fork=yes' equivalent? It's been ages since I've last worked 
with Ant

Comment: You are right, it should be fork="true", It was but I tried many things, I made a mistake when setting it back. Apparently it is equivalent since an error indicates that the tests are not forked otherwise. I switched it back to fork="true" and could not see any change in the result.

Comment: Thank you it was indeed the fork parameter that was causing the issue but the one in batchtest, not in junit ;)

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, for me my junit wasn't proper.
Follow the link [here](http://javaworld-abhinav.blogspot.com/2014/06/automating-code-coverage-and-junit.html)